# How can we make the server side API details configurable after build in LWC OSS single page application?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-oss

I am trying to build an LWC OSS app. The Sever side logic is written using a express JS, which is currently running in local host. I need to create a build of my LWC oss application and need to make the Api details configurable(In express we can achieve this by environment variables). What are the approach i should take?

Comment: Are you running the server separate from the SPA, or is it supposed to be part of it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Yes it is separate.

Comment: I am looking for a solution how i can make few things configurable from an  .env or config.js file which may be available in root of the build or something..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be looking for something like [The Twelve-Factor App](https://12factor.net/) (see factor III).

On Heroku and Heroku-like application hosting platforms, these configuration values are called *config vars* (or a similar term, depending on the platform). They are exposed to your application as environment variables.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response! Its clear that i should be using some environment variables, but my question is more specific to LWC OSS. I didnt find any documentation on how to impliment it using LWC OSS....
I have implimented the same in Express js and hosted in several placesmaking use of environment variables .

Comment: LWC OSS doesn't have any functionality to consume environment vars. This capability comes from your build system/bundler. For example, you  use a Webpack [`EnvironmentPlugin`](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/environment-plugin/) to consume default env values if you're building using webpack.